# Timestamp update ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have wrote this code to insert data in my database:

```
 // performing sql query

 $sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`, `duration`) 
     VALUES ('$title', '$artist', '$duration') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time";
```

time is the column for timestamp.

I just need to update the timestamp witch is auto, when a duplicate key is found, but it gives me an error, i looked but i cannot find the answer.

Comment: If the timestamp is automatically updated you could use:  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`, `duration`) VALUES ('$title', '$artist', '$duration') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=NOW()
```

Comment: I found the answer for my self, witch is this one, thank you @niklon, i will still mark this one right, for other people.